# Detect duplicate columns in SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am fetching employer records by the field `emp_id` and I would like to print the full name instead of only his first, if more than one row share same value in `First`.

Also how would I have to adapt the conditional expression to work with the new query?

This is the code I am trying to fix:

```
<?php
$emp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employees
WHERE s_id = '" .$s. "' ORDER BY emp_id ASC");
while($names = mysql_fetch_array($emp)) { 
if ($names['Show'] == 'TRUE'){
?>
        <table width="100%" class="round1" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td height="7.5%" class="name_phone"
                    <div>
                        <?php 
                        if (($names['First'] == $names['First']) && ($names['u_id'] != $names['u_id']))
                        {echo $names['First'];}
                        else
                        {echo $names['First']. ' ' .$names['Last'];} ?>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="phone">
                    <div>
                        <?php if ($names['ShowPhone'] == 'TRUE')
                        {echo $names['Phone'];}
                        else
                        {echo '&nbsp;';} ?>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<?php }} ?>
```

Comment: `=` isn't a comparison operator!

Comment: = is an assignment operator, as in to assign a variable a value

Comment: Where do you pull the names from ? And why are you comparing a variable to itself?

Comment: I am creating a scheudle type of site where the names are on the left side and if that person has the same first name as another it will show their last name also to tell the difference and I'm pulling the names from the same table as the u_id's

Comment: What you are basically doing is fetching a value and comparing it to itself, `$names['First'] == $names['First']` always returns true

Comment: I also changed ($names['First'] = $names['First']) && ($names['u_id'] = $names['u_id']) to ($names['First'] == $names['First']) && ($names['u_id'] != $names['u_id']) with the same results

Comment: I know that's why I am asking, where you get it from, MySQLi query perhaps?

Comment: tried what you posted earlier a3f, and now the variables are not defined correctly... more homework for me I suppose...

Comment: I edited your question to make it clearer, let's hope someone more familiar with sql syntax will help you out :)

Comment: I think what you should do is alter all tables you got and add a new column like `ShowName` which has value 1 or 0 depending on whether the first name is duplicated and then when you are going to fetch the record check for `$names['ShowName']` and echo based on that, and in future when you add a new record, add a value to `ShowName` based on whether a SELECT statement for that `First` returns any values

Comment: probably the best option for me atm. kind of new to this if you haven't noticed  :/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double `==` for an equality comparison.

```
<?php 
if (($names['First'] == $names['First']) && ($names['u_id'] != $names['u_id']))
{echo $names['First'];}
else
{echo $names['First']. ' ' .$names['Last'];}
?>
```

[Comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 0):

For comparisons in php you use `==` or `===` (or `!=` or `!==` in your case), you are using the assignment operator.

Comment: I understand that. I'm just wondering why it's echoing everyone with their first and last names like that and not just the people with the same first name...

Answer (score 0):

FIX CODE:

```
     <?php 
                        if (($names['First'] == $names['First']) && ($names['u_id'] == $names['u_id']))
                        {echo $names['First'];}
                        else
                        {echo $names['First']. ' ' .$names['Last'];}
 ?>
```

Comment: oops.. I meant the opposite u_id's are different it should show the first and last, but only the first of the people that do not have the same first name...